# Como capturar valor JavaScript com PHP

Tags: php, javascript

O `input` abaixo é carregado juntamente com o script da página:

```
$("[name='estado-cliente']").attr('value', obj['uf_cliente']);
```

Contudo, este valor será utilizado para uma comparação em PHP.

Já tentei o seguinte, mas sem sucesso:

**JavaScript:**

```
var valor = $("[name='estado-cliente']").val();
```

**PHP:**

```
$estado_cliente = "<script> document.write(valor)</script>";
```

Obs.: consigo exibir um `alert` logo após o `attr` do valor desejado, porém ao carregar a página e dar um `echo`, em `$estado_cliente`, nada é exibido.

Comment: Você consegue exibir um alerta porque é javascript e portanto rodando na sua máquina.

Answer (score 0):

Como o amigo **Leo Caracciolo** disse, o Javascript neste caso, roda no navegador do usuário, isto significa que só é possível enviar informações para o php através de requisições HTTP.

Funcionaria assim:
O php enviar as informações pro navegador->
O usuário insere os dados ->
O javascript envia as informações de volta para o php através de Ajax->
O Javascript recebe os dados tratados

O Ajax permite que sejam enviadas requisições http sem recarregar a tela, uma função ajax recebe a resposta do php como se estivéssemos acessando a página, ou seja, recebe tudo o que seria exibido na tela se acessássemos através do navegador normalmente.

Crie uma página php que faça o tratamento que você precisa e dê um echo no resultado para que o ajax o capture. Mais ou menos assim:

HTML:

```
<input name="estado-cliente">
<button>
  enviar
</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Voce precisa de um evento que envie a requisição
$('button').click(function(){
    $.post("SUAPAGINA.PHP?estado-cliente=" + $('name="estado-cliente"').val(), function(dados){
    //faça o que quiser com os dados
    })
})
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $dados = $_POST["estado-cliente"];

  // trate os dados como desejado e de um echo no resultado, pode usar JSON tbm, mas assim é mais simples.


  echo $resultado;
```